# How to assign values to checkboxes in CheckedListBox in Powershell studio

Tags: powershell, powershell-studio

I have a CheckedListBox in my GUI that displays each one of the roles I need to present to the user, as pictured below:[image]

Each one of these roles is tied to specific number in the database, as pictured here:[image]

As you can see, the role `AUDIT` is assigned to the number `10`. I need to reflect this in my GUI somehow. What I need is for the value of each of these check boxes in the CheckedListBox to equal one of these ROLESID numbers.

My dilemma is that I want to continue to use the CheckedListBox because of how easy they are to use. I could very well give each one of them their own individual checkbox and assign the values from there, but that's just a lot of bloated code. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please post the code for this.

Comment: I actually don't have any sort of code for those checkboxes, as it was all created through the GUI editor. My hope is to avoid creating a checkbox for each one of the roles. I could very well do that and it would work, but I feel that there's a better way and I was hoping to see if anyone knew of one.

Comment: I have limited experience with graphical controls. But I'm sure that each checkbox has its own value. And you could always use a hash table to translate if it came down to it. Without code, I have no way to research this and provide an answer. Even if you are using a GUI designer, there is code somewhere.